# Display an html div block differently depending on the extended page using django templatin

Tags: html, django

I'm building a webpage using the extend templating feature of django. I thus have a base.html where I have search fields that I want to display differently depending on the webpage that is extending base.html. Here are the fields that I want to show: 
[image]

The corresponding code is:

```
<div class="row">
         <div class="container-fluid col-md-offset-9 col-md-3">
          <a href="../posts/newpost/" class="btn btn-info" role="button">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education" aria-hidden="true"></span> Buton
       </a>
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 id="Titre" align="center">Title </h1><br>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-12" style="height:100px;"></div>

<form class="form-inline text-center" action="{% url 'posts:postsearch' %}"  id="form-searchLessons">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="typeCours" list="matieres" placeholder="Keyword" name="discipline" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="Localisation" placeholder="Lieu."
          name="localisation" onFocus="geolocate()">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="btn-getLessons">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span> Trouver !
  </button>
</form>
</div>
```

In case of page1, I want the fields to appear like the image above. 
Then if I extend base.html from page2, this should like this:

[image]

Which currently I write a complete different page:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row reduced_search-bar">
      <div class="col-lg-9">

         <form class="form-inline">
           <div class="form-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="typeCours" placeholder="Keyword">
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Localisation" placeholder="Lieu">
           </div>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span> Trouver !
           </button>
         </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
              <a href="{%  url 'posts:add' %}" class="btn btn-info" role="button">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education" aria-hidden="true"></span> Buton ?
              </a>
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

What I want, is to have all this code in one single base.html. That I print differently depending whether I'm extending from page1, or page2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you can pass an extra context from your view which will determine which code to show:

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

def page1(request):
    return render(request, 'page1.html')

def page2(request):
    return render(request, 'page2.html', {'page2': True})

# base.html
{% if page2 %}
    # Necessary code for page 2
{% else %}
    # Necessary code for other pages
{% endif %}

# page1.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

# page2.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```